# Passing a value outside the form to another page in url PHP

Tags: php, html

Im trying to build a web app where a user selects the value from a dropdown list and clicks the button next to the item. But only the value of select gets sent over to the next page.

```
  echo "<td>".$row["idTaco"]."</td><td>".$row["nameTaco"]."</td><td>".$row["priceTaco"]."</td><td>".$row["descTaco"]."</td>";
    ?>
<td>
  <form action="Includes/dodajVKosarico.inc.php?idTaco="<?php $row["idTaco"] ?> method="get">
    <select name="kolicina">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class = "dodaj">Dodaj</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

The `row['idTaco']` works fine in the echo but when i try to send it using this form i cant pass the value to another page. Im sorry im still new to this.

Comment: You have missed **”** this , in your action

Comment: You are sending this form to `Includes/dodajVKosarico.inc.php?idTaco=`, because that is the value of your `action` attribute. Fix your quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a query string value, one (arguably neater and easier to see) option is to just add the value again as a hidden field in your form, then it will get submitted along with the rest of the form data.

```
<form action="Includes/dodajVKosarico.inc.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="idTaco" value="<?php echo $row["idTaco"] ?>"/>
...etc
```

Or you could just fix the broken quotes (and missing `echo`) in your existing code:

```
action="Includes/dodajVKosarico.inc.php?idTaco=<?php echo $row["idTaco"] ?>"
```

Comment: You forget **name** attribute , to access that variable which is passed in form

Comment: You are missing the `name`  attribute for the hidden field.

Comment: Thanks a lot! up until now didnt know about the hidden trick. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine just missing an echo before your $row["idTaco"], You must do as follows:

```
 <form action="Includes/dodajVKosarico.inc.php?idTaco=<?php echo $row['idTaco']; ?>" method="get">
```

Comment: No. In this case the action of the form is still `Includes/dodajVKosarico.inc.php?idTaco=`. Even with an echo, the value is still outside the quote marks, so it's not considered part of the attribute.

Comment: No problem, could add single quotation then, as I edited.

Comment: No, you've missed the point, it's nothing to do with single quotes. Let's say the row value is `3`. The final output of this code will be `<form action="Includes/dodajVKosarico.inc.php?idTaco="3 method="get">`. Notice how the `3` is all by itself in the middle of the HTML, not inside the "action" attribute. See my answer for the right version.

Comment: You are right, but It was a typo, I should have add double qutation after ?>, how ever the point is both. using echo here is a must.

Comment: Ok now it's better - thanks for updating. Although, I think in the description you should also point out that the quote mark must be moved. Your statement "Everything is fine" is not true because that quote mark is also a problem in the original code, not just the missing echo.